# Twilio HTTP error and Google Spreadsheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, google-api, twilio

When I reply to the message, if I enter "Yes", "yes", or "no", it will give me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in **call**
>           return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
>           response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
>           reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
>           response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
>           rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
>           reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
>           rv = self.dispatch_request()
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
>           return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
>         File "/Users/ryankenny/Desktop/Phase2.py/Test.py", line 59, in hello_guest
>           wks_attendees.update_acell('E'+str(num), int(wks_attendees.acell('E' +str(num)).value) + 1)
>       NameError: global name 'num' is not defined

If I enter anything else, it replies with:

> You sent a different keyword, we need a yes or a no, you sent:....".

Here is my code:
I named this one Test.py

```
from __future__ import print_function
import oauth2client
import gspread
import httplib2
import os
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client, tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from flask import Flask,render_template, url_for, request, redirect, make_response
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from twilio.rest  import Client
import time
import json
import gspread


app = Flask(__name__)
json_key = json.load(open('client_secret.json'))
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open("list18") #add your workbook name here
wks_attendees = wks.get_worksheet(0) #attendees worksheet
# ACCOUNT_SID = os.environ['Twilio_account_per']
# AUTH_TOKEN = os.environ['Twilio_account_token_per']
ACCOUNT_SID = 'xxxxxxxxx'
AUTH_TOKEN = 'xxxxxx'
client = Client(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)
@app.route("/messages", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_guest():

    resp = MessagingResponse()
    from_number = request.values.get('From', None)
    from_body = request.values.get('Body', None)
    number = from_number
    body_strip = from_body.lower()
    if "yes" in body_strip:
        # We have a keeper! Find the attendee and update their confirmation_status
        wks_attendees.update_acell("F"+str(guest_confirmation_cell.row), 'Accepted')  # update the status to accepted for that guest
        resp.message(u"\u2665" + "Thanks for confirming, we'll be in touch!" + u"\u2665")  # respond to the guest with a confirmation!
    elif "no" in from_body.lower():
        # update the confirmation_status row to declined for that guest
        wks_attendees.update_acell("F"+str(guest_confirmation_cell.row), 'Declined')
        # respond to the user confirming the action
        resp.message("Sorry to hear that, we still love you though!")
    else:  # respond with invalid keyword
        resp.message("You sent a different keyword, we need a yes or a no, you sent: "+
                     from_body)
    return str(resp)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I named this one sheets.py

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, url_for, request, redirect, make_response
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from twilio.rest  import Client
import time
import json
import gspread
import os
import Test


# app = Flask(__name__)
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

#credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'].encode(), scope)
#credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'].encode(), scope)
#gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open("list18") #add your workbook name here
wks_attendees = wks.get_worksheet(0) #attendees worksheet
# ACCOUNT_SID = os.environ['Twilio_account_per']
# AUTH_TOKEN = os.environ['Twilio_account_token_per']
ACCOUNT_SID = 'xxxxxxxx'
AUTH_TOKEN = 'xxxxxx'
client = Client(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)


for num in range(2,4):  #to iterate between guests, amend this based on your total
    print("sleeping for 2 seconds")
    time.sleep(2) #adding a delay to avoid filtering
    guest_number = wks_attendees.acell('B' +str(num)).value
    guest_name = wks_attendees.acell('A'+str(num)).value

    if not guest_number:
        print(guest_name + ' telephone number empty not messaging')
        wks_attendees.update_acell('E'+str(num), '0') #set number to 0

    else:
        print('Sending message to ' + guest_name)
        client.messages.create(
        to="+" + guest_number,
        from_="16467830828", #your twilio number here
        body= u"\u2B50" + u"\u2764" + u"\u2B50" + u"\u2764" + u"\u2B50" + u"\u2764" + u"\u2B50" + u"\u2764" + "\n\n" + u"\u2709" +" Save the date! "+ u"\u2709" +"\n\nRyan Kenny and Rachel Hunt are delighted to invite you to our wedding.\n\nDate: \n\nPlace. Please text YES if you are saving the date and can join us or text NO if sadly, you won't be able to be with us.\n\n" u"\u2B50" + u"\u2764" + u"\u2B50" + u"\u2764" + u"\u2B50" + u"\u2764" + u"\u2B50" + u"\u2764",
        #body ="Hello you lovely people, tomorrow is the big day!!\n\nPost code for the venue: CM6 1RQ\n\nArrival time one thirty for a two o'clock ceremony.\n\nIt is a cash bar, so please bring sufficient money with you as there is no nearby cash machine.\n\nIt might be raining at some point in the day, so an umbrella might be required.\n\nThe venue is non smoking, due to the thatched buildings.\n\nWe could not be more excited that you are joining us for our special day and looking forward to sharing great food and good times!\n\nTom & Lauren",
        )
        wks_attendees.update_acell('E'+str(num), int(wks_attendees.acell('E' +str(num)).value) + 1) #increment the message count row
else:                  # else part of the loop
    print('finished')
```

Updated WORKING test.py code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import oauth2client
import gspread
import httplib2
import os
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client, tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from flask import Flask,render_template, url_for, request, redirect, make_response
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from twilio.rest  import Client
import time
import json
import gspread


app = Flask(__name__)
json_key = json.load(open('client_secret.json'))
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open("list18") #add your workbook name here
wks_attendees = wks.get_worksheet(0) #attendees worksheet

ACCOUNT_SID = 'AC08bde2cb40b78d7f1022ba85d6dba741'
AUTH_TOKEN = '3a74f56d324f519b980f1553f1d0ae89'
client = Client(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)
@app.route("/messages", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_guest():

    resp = MessagingResponse()
    from_number = request.values.get('From', None)
    from_body = request.values.get('Body', None)
    number = from_number
    body_strip = from_body.lower()
    clean_number = number.strip("+")
    guest_confirmation_cell = wks_attendees.find(str(clean_number).strip())
    if "yes" in body_strip:
        # We have a keeper! Find the attendee and update their confirmation_status
        wks_attendees.update_acell("F"+str(guest_confirmation_cell.row), 'Accepted')  # update the status to accepted for that guest
        #wks_attendees.update_acell('E'+str(num), int(wks_attendees.acell('E' +str(num)).value) + 1)

        resp.message(u"\u2665" + "Thanks for confirming, we'll be in touch!" + u"\u2665")  # respond to the guest with a confirmation!
    elif "no" in from_body.lower():
        # update the confirmation_status row to declined for that guest
        wks_attendees.update_acell("F"+str(guest_confirmation_cell.row), 'Declined')
        # respond to the user confirming the action
        resp.message("Sorry to hear that, we still love you though!")
    else:  # respond with invalid keyword
        resp.message("You sent a different keyword, we need a yes or a no, you sent: "+
                     from_body)
    return str(resp)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Removed repetition and re-arranged question to make things read in a more logical order. Added blockquote formatting for response messages. Added a little whitespace in the code to make it easier to read.

Comment: The error message you're getting says `NameError: global name 'num' is not defined` but the line it's referencing (where it says `wks_attendees.update_acell('E'+str(num),...` isn't in the code you provided. Are you sure you're trying to run the same file you're editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer of that app/Twilio Onboarding here.

It looks like you have condensed the code from the repo somewhat, you are attempting to use a variable `num` that hasn't been declared so Python is erroring out. That variable is used to set [the length of the spreadsheet](https://github.com/SeekTom/Twilio/blob/32e1718508042e0f6435c61da3611354fc8e7f28/Wedication/chase.py#L20)
during the create of the for loop that iterates over the list of attendees in the spreadsheet to update their status.

If you share the complete file or at least the code near line 59 I can help further.

Comment: Thank you Tom. I just edited the code above. Please let me know if you have a solution. :) I appreciate everything.

Comment: "/Users/ryankenny/Desktop/Phase2.py/Test.py", line 59, in hello_guest wks_attendees.update_acell('E'+str(num), int(wks_attendees.acell('E' +str(num)).value) + 1) 

Have you shared the latest version of the error? As the code in test.py doesnt match.

One other thing I noted in test.py is you are missing:

number = from_number
clean_number = number.strip("+")
guest_confirmation_cell = wks_attendees.find(str(clean_number).strip())

As they will be needed when you want to actually update the guests confirmation status

Can you add them in and re run test.py

Comment: Thank you Tom. I'm going to re-edit my code to my recent changes. I added 
from_number clean_number = number.strip("+") and guest_confirmation_cell =wks_attendees.find(str(clean_number).strip()). However, 
where would this go and what would it actually do if my code is already working? wks_attendees.update_acell('E'+str(num), int(wks_attendees.acell('E' +str(num)).value) + 1)? 
There isn't anymore errors. However, I do have another question.  I'm using ngrok for an http tunnel. I only get 8 hours though before I need to get a new one.  Is there any way I can prolong the use, or refresh it?

Comment: Where you have it in the revised code is fine. wks_attendees.update_acell('E'+str(num), int(wks_attendees.acell('E' +str(num)).value) + 1) just updates the amount of messages sent to that particular guest.

Re ngrok you can pay for an upgrade to get a permentant tunnel, or do what I did for my wedding and host it on [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python)

Comment: Thank you very much Tom. You  have been alot of help.